# Condition Filter not showing data google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, measurement-protocol

I added the analytic in my webpage.When i started to generate the reports i am unable to get that in following condition

1. I create the dimension1 with name SessionD and send there data.
2. In Behavior report i add the condition where SessionD='nitin' (I already send 2 time this value)
3. After test i receive that its show some % session available
4. Problem come here when i click on preview its not showing single report don't know why.

Please find the attached screen shot for same.[Image](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=bc6c341)

Here i want that there should show the session for this also as there are x number or session present as per the test connection(i also send there data) but which is not coming.Am i doing any thing wrong?

Code added to webpage:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': '/'+eLabel, 'title': eLabel, 'SessionD': gaUser, 'dimension1': gaUser, 'SessionDD': '1', 'metric1':'1' });
```

Thanks,
Nitin Gaikwad

Comment: how are you populating the value of dimension1?

Comment: yes if you see the attached image you can see this.I added dimension1 name as SessionD

Comment: Let me try again. Could you post the code you have added to your website to fill in the value of Dimension1? You stated "and send there data." How are you sending the data?   Something like this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Here is the code which i try.

ga('send', 'pageview', {
        'page': '/'+eLabel,
        'title': eLabel,
        'SessionD': gaUser,
        'dimension1': gaUser,
     'SessionDD': '1',
     'metric1':'1'
      
      });

Comment: dimension1 is a string and probably needs to be enclosed with in quotes.

Comment: Yes gaUser And eLabel both are string and sending string data only

Comment: Or do u wanna say that i add 'dimension1': ''+gaUser

Comment: You  are using parameters that I don't believe exist for the pageview, such as SessionD and SessionDD. If those are your dimensions, then you would use the dimension1 or dimension2 name.

Comment: I Added SessionD as dimension and SessionDD as metric both are customize variable.